# Two ID fields in one collection

Tags: mongodb

I would like to understand how to do the following when inserting a new collection in MongoDB.

As understand it, a new ObjectID is generated for each record (using SQL terminology here) inserted into a collection -  you do not have to specify an ID field.

Now I already have  a User Profiles collection and I want to create a User Rating collection, where forum users rate other forum users.

The collection would include a rating (1-5) but I also want to specify an ID field for the user being rated ('User_Rated_ID', and the individual who rates him/her('User_Rater').

This is where I get a bit confused, as for each new record in the User Profiles collection, a unique object ID will be generated. Should IDs generated from that collection be used when I want to a insert a new record into the 'User Rating' collection?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this depending upon the access path of your data, but to think of it in a relational sense your `UserRating` collection would have three ids: a surrogate id that identifies the document, the raterId, an `_id` from `User` that corresponds to the user who did the rating, and the `ratedId`, an `_id` from `User` that corresponds to the user who was rated.

This will allow you to query for ratings that correspond to a user or rater by their `_id`.

Comment: Thanks. So if say MongoDB assigned ID = 2 and ID = 3 for my second and third  'records' in the User collection (I know the actual generated ID is much longer, like 24 characters), and the user with the ID = 2, is rating the user with the ID = 3 (and gave the user ID = 3, a rating of of four), then I'd insert 4 in the rating row, Rater_ID = 2, and Rater_ID = 3 ?

Comment: `{ rating: 4, raterId: raterUser._id, ratedId: ratedUser._id }` -- it depends on how you're actually doing the inserting.